# Best way to limit results to the authenticated user in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, model

I am using Laravel 5.1 for an application, and have two models. Clients and Users. Users that are authenticated and logged in, should only view their own clients. That query is pretty simple:

```
$clients = Client::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

But how can I have an edit route for a client, that other user does not have access to. Currently I have:

```
$client = Client::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->find($id);
```

This works perfectly fine, but I love how that `findOrFail()` function works, and it's so simple.

Should I add custom method in the model?

Answer (score 1):

```
$clients = Auth::user()->clients();
```

Should work if you have the proper hasmany relationship set in the user model. The relationship I would add to the User model is (assuming the clients model is Client.php):

```
public function clients()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Client');
}
```

This is also assuming you have a foreign key in the client table called "user_id".